# Loop through and compare spreadsheet cells in Python

Tags: python, excel

Please excuse the crude code and I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish this but I am new to programming. Basically I have an excel file with 2 sheets, sheet 1 is populated in column A, sheet 2 is populated in A, B, and C. I want to run through all of the cells in sheet 1 column A searching for a match in sheet 2 column A and copy the info from B and C to sheet 1 if found. The code below kind of works, it copies some data and populates it but it doesn't really match up correctly and it seems to skip a lot of cells if they are the same value as the previous cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('spreadsheet.xlsx')

sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')

for row in sheet1['A1':'A200']:
    for cell in row:
        obj1 = cell.value
        for row2 in sheet2['A1':'A2000']:
            for cell2 in row2:
                obj2 = cell2.value
                if obj1 == obj2:
                    row = str(cell2.row)
                    site = 'B' + row
                    tic = 'C' + row
                    sheet1[site] = sheet2[site].value
                    sheet1[tic] = sheet2[tic].value

wb.save('spreadsheet2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please include an image of what you are getting and what you expect. It is unclear as the question is currently stated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but if I understand you correctly this should help:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('spreadsheet.xlsx')

sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
sheet2 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')


for i in range(1, 201):
    if sheet1.cell(row = i, column = 1).value == sheet2.cell(row = i, column = 1).value:
        sheet1.cell(row = i, column = 2).value = sheet2.cell(row = i, column = 2).value
        sheet1.cell(row = i, column = 3).value = sheet2.cell(row = i, column = 3).value


wb.save('spreadsheet2.xlsx')
```

I was able to clean up the code by the using the `.cell()` method.  If this isn't what you need just comment and tell me what exactly you are trying to do.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I just added another for loop in front of the one you created and it did exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!!

Comment: I just added `for h in range(1,2000):` above your loop and replaced the sheet1 rows to = h instead of i.  To explain my initial goal more clearly: sheet2 was populated with 200 key values (col A) with associated attributes (col B, C). Sheet1 was filled with 2000 key values but no attributes, many were duplicates and all of them matched one of the key values from sheet2. So for every value in sheet1, I needed to search through sheet2 and copy the matching attributes.

Comment: Great, I am glad I was able to help you out.  All the stuff I learned about the `openpyxl` module was found here: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/ It is a great website and gives a lot of great information. A word of caution: if you use it, some of the data on that website is old and no longer works. The styling for example doesn't work how they show, however there are other pages about styling with `openpyxl` so I was able to fix the issues I had. Happy programming!